# how to filter certain branch say, 'master' in my parameterized build run in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have parameterized jenkins job which takes branch name in order to build that particular branch. I want job to not run if some body puts "master" as a branch name but run job for every other branches. I want to basically build it from bugfix branch.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Validating String Input Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin) to add validation of the parameter before the build and give the user an error if the branch equals "master". Also, `^(?!master).*$` is an regular expression which doesn't allow the string master, but any other string.

Comment: Yep looks like this is what I want. I will try this plugin! Thanks!